# Need help figuring out what to proxy whitelist for One Drive program updates

Tags: onedrive-for-business

Having a difficult time figuring out exactly what is causing the issue. I have tested updating onedrive on and off our network and clearly our proxy is blocking something. But I have not been able to single out exactly what it is. Anyone else with experience with this have any knowledge on this? The IPs in the MS KB article seem to all be working. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide